# Converting Urls to imageviews and add dynamically to gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i`m new in Android and i need some help I want to set a gridview with 3 imagebuttons by sending an array of stringurls to the imageAdapter, i first took the urls from a webservice ans returned them to my fragment class where a the gridview is placed. The arraylist consists out of objects with the url string set. I have no clue how i can load the gridview with these urls, should i convert them to drawables? I saw some posts about using asynchtask ? Can someone help me out? And i actually need imagebuttons or can i connect an click listener to the imageviews?

Start methode in fragment class after downloading the urls form webservice

```
@Override
     public void updateScreenMovies(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
        gvNieuw.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),movies));

    }
```

ImageAdapter class:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    Drawable[] drawableArray = new Drawable[3];

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
        mContext = c;
        this.movies = movies;
    }



    public int getCount() {
        return drawableArray.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = null;

        // how to convert string url to imageview?



        imageView = new ImageButton(mContext);
        imageView.setId(position);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 250));

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple, use picaso lib http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```